# How can I set a picture to a table value? (love2d)

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm doing a start menu for my game in Love2d. I need buttons for my "start game" and "quit game", of course. I know how to use text for buttons, but I do not know how to use actual pictures. I'm basing myself on [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQc7csvghrM&playnext=1&list=PL1E781C07DF94A786&feature=results_video).

Help, please?

Answer (score 2):

You are going to want to load your menu images into a `love.load()` function and draw it in a `love.draw()` function .

For instance, I make a file called menu.lua where I keep all my relevant menu data. menu.lua starts with `menu = {}` which will create a new table called `menu` . Then, in menu.lua:

```
function menu.load()
    menu.start.img = love.graphics.newImage("start.jpg") -- load start.jpg
    menu.exit.img = love.graphics.newImage("exit.jpg") -- load exit.jpg
end

function menu.draw()
    love.graphics.draw(menu.start.img,x,y) -- draw start.jpg at (x,y)
    love.graphics.draw(menu.exit.img,x,y) -- draw exit.jpg at (x,y)
end
```

After that, you call `menu.load()` and `menu.draw()` in your main.lua file.

That's how you load an image into a table and draw it.

The [LOVE wiki](https://www.love2d.org/wiki/love) can help you with these sort of questions.

Answer (score 1):

First, use `img = love.graphics.newImage('filename_here.png')` to load an image into the variable `img`.  Then, use `love.graphics.draw(img, 50, 50)` to draw that image at coordinates 50, 50.  Make sure you only load the image once though.  If you

Comment: The suspense is killing me.